ArduPilot plugin for gazebo documentation
i'm trying to simulate a cessna 172 using Gazebo garden, and i'd like to control it within the simulation using the ArduPilot plugin. I've seen on the official websites some examples using the zephyr delta wing and the iris quadcopter, however these only provide the .sdf models, with no in-depth explanation of how the plugin works whatsoever. Is there any kind of documentation regarding it? I've tried looking online to no avail, all i cand find are old questions in forums and/or dead links

The plugin in ardupilot_gazebo is used to control joints in the model and send the state of the vehicle back to the controller. Additional plugins are used in the vehicle sdf files to model aerodynamics and other properties (for example buoyancy if modelling a boat).
The ardupilot_gazebo plugin receives a vector of PWM values from the flight controller. What the plugin does with these is determined by the <control> elements in the plugin sdf. One of three things may happen: the PWM value is used to control a joint  velocity directly (such as a multi-rotor motor speed), the PWM is used to control a joint position directly (such as a plane control surface), or the PWM is forwarded onto a topic on the gz-transport message bus where is subscribed to by another Gazebo plugin (such as a thruster or joint controller).
The iris and zephyr examples in the main repo use the first two methods. There are also variations of the iris model where the PWM is forwarded to the joint position controllers of an attached gimbal. For further examples of other types of vehicle look at the example in ArduPilot/SITL_Models

If you want some raw details, you will have to dig through some code, which you can find here. You can also check other folders in there for more examples and details.

i really only wanted to know which parameters to plug in the various tags, and what tags are needed in the .sdf file, i can look through the code but i hoped there was some kind of very basic documentation since i don't need that level of insight
